# Reverse convolution

Tags: discrete-signals, convolution, inverse

I was reading about linear systems and random processes and I came across this

$$h_{k}*h_{-k}*rxx[k].$$

I know what convolution is and its formula. Does the minus sign affect both of the parameters in the convolution or just k:
$$h_{k}*h_{-k}$$

Is the multiplication in the summmation equal to any of these?

1. $h[k]h[i-k]$
2. $h[k]h[k+i]$

Comment: A) is convolution and B) is autocorrelation.

Comment: I try to workout $$h_{k}*h_{-k}*rxx[k].$$ given that $$rxx[k] = \delta (k)$$ and using this formula of convolution I get wrong answer. First I convolve $$h_{-k}*rxx[k].$$ and then the rest. Can you walk me through please

Comment: What I get after the first convolution is:$$h[k]*h[-k]$$ and the answer is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} h[i]h[k+i] $$which does not agree with the above.

Comment: @DilipSawarte Do you have further thoughts on this one or why this would have appeared??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we treat $h_k$ as the coefficients of a filter (or a channel), the expression $h_k \star h_{-k}$ is the cascade of a forward filter with the reverse filter (the coefficients are reversed in time).  As written, and assuming $h_k$ is real, this would result in a "zero-phase" filter, or if additional delay elements are added a "linear phase filter".  Generally for complex coefficients, the reverse filter should also be conjugated: $h_{-k}^*$

The magnitude response in the frequency domain for $h_k$ and $h_{-k}^*$ are the same, therefore $h_k \star h_{-k}^*$ would have the cascaded response of both filters.

There is nothing further we can decide about the autocorrelation function $r_{xx}[k]$ without further knowledge about $x[k]$. For example, if $x[k]$ was white noise, then  $r_{xx}[k] = \delta[k]$ (the unit sample function). But we cannot from the information given decide that is the case.

That said, what we can deduce is the phase of the channel or filter $h_k$ is eliminated, and its magnitude response is squared, and this magnitude only result is convolved with the autocorrelation of $x[k]$.

Comment: @DilipSawarte Do you have further thoughts on this one or why this would have appeared??

Comment: See my answer below.  The poster formerly known as DilipSarwate.

Comment: @makala- Thanks for the check but consider selecting Dilip’s answer as the “correct answer” instead— even though my answer is not incorrect, he provides the fuller picture and mine just adds further insight.

Answer (score 1):

The formula quoted by the OP is better expressed as $h \star \tilde{h} \star R_{X,X}$ with $\star$ denoting convolution and the sequence $\tilde{h}$ being defined via $\tilde{h}[k] = h[-k]~\forall k \in \mathbb Z$. The result comes from the study of random processes as they pass through linear systems. If the *wide-sense-stationary* discrete-time random process $\{X[k]\colon k \in \mathbb Z\}$ with autocorrelation function $R_{X,X}[k] = E\big[X[n]X[n+k]\big]$ is the input to a BIBO-stable time-invariant discrete-time linear system (note the lack of insistence on causality for the system) with impulse response $h$, then the output process $\{Y[k]\colon k \in \mathbb Z\}$ is also a wide-sense-stationary discrete-time process whose autocorrelation function is given by
$$R_{Y,Y} = E\big[Y[n]Y[n+k]\big] = h \star \tilde{h} \star R_{X,X}.$$
The key to understanding this result is to  write it as
$$R_{Y,Y} = \big(h \star \tilde{h}\big) \star R_{X,X}$$ and notice that $\big(h \star \tilde{h}\big) = R_{h,h}$ is the *autocorrelation function* of the discrete-time *sequence* $h$. The disbelievers are asked to calculate the $k$-th term of the convolution as follows:
\begin{align}
\big(h \star \tilde{h}\big)[k] &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty h[k-n]\tilde{h}[n]\\
&= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty h[k-n]{h}[-n]\\
&= \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty h[k+m]{h}[m]&\scriptstyle{\text{on setting } -n = m}~ \text{and reordering the sum}\\
&= \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty {h}[m]h[k+m] &\scriptstyle{\text{for those who insist on specific forms}}\\
&= R_{h,h}[k]  
\end{align}
Thus, $R_{Y,Y}$ is the convolution of $R_{h,h}$ with $R_{X,X}$. Interestingly, since autocorrelation functions are *even* functions of their arguments, we could also claim with perfect truth that the output autocorrelation function is the cross-correlation between the input autocorrelation and the system autocorrelation. After all, "flipping (either) function over" before sliding in computing the convolution is unnecessary: an even function flipped over is the same as the unflipped function!

In terms of Fourier transforms, the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation function of a random process is called the power spectral density function of the process, and
$$R_{Y,Y} = \big(h \star \tilde{h}\big) \star R_{X,X} \implies
S_{Y,Y}(f) = |H(f)|^2 S_{X,X}(f)$$ where $S$ denotes power spectral density and $|H(f)|^2$ is called the *power transfer function* of the system with impulse response $h$ and transfer function (a.k.a. Fourier transform) $H$. Note that the Fourier transform of $\tilde{h}$ is $H^*(f)$.

Comment: Very very nice on giving the complete picture - thanks Dilip!